# Identifying a type of Pizza Topping

Tags: pizza, dessert, food-identification, savoury

I was looking at the tiny nation of Brunei on Google Maps, and I noticed they have a Pizza-Hut there, not too many details but a few photos were attached and there was a Pizza that I didn't recognise, although I must say it looked rather intriguing!
If I'm totally honest, I don't even know if it is savoury or some kind of dessert, so I have attached a copy.

I did attempt a reverse image search but I couldn't seem to see a very similar match, so I hope that the experts here might know?

[image: Brunei Pizza Hut example]
.
I will be very grateful if someone can identify this, or even perhaps have a recipe?

Yours, Humbly!
Hungry from Heanor :)

Comment: The Brunei  pizzahut website could help you, 
https://www.pizzahut.com.bn/Menu/Pizzas
but I did not find anything that looks like that (or maybe it's one of the Hawaiian pizza ?)

Comment: @Max Thanks! I'm ashamed that I didn't even consider reading their website, I guess I presumed it wouldn't be able to read it ... However, thanks to your prompt, I have tweeted their Brunei branch. It will be interesting to read their reply. Thanks again!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can understand your confusion, but this is assuredly *not* a dessert pizza. The white circles of sauce, while they look like icing in appearance, <s>are actually **Ranch Dressing**.</s>

For comparison, here is a pizza that someone made themselves [on Reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/food/comments/hpyf0g/chicken_bacon_ranch_pizza_i_ate_frozen_grocery/) While I wouldn't say it is *common* to put ranch on pizza, it is definitely something that people do, for better or for worse.  (See Edit)

The rest of the pizza is a bit more difficult to identify. I can see that there are chunks of lean meat, which I initially assumed were tomatoes, but I believe the texturing and crisp edges indicate meat more than tomato. It's hard at the moment to know which, specifically.

It might be the end of the answer here. However, the piece of information that this is specific to the Brunei pizza hut allowed me to finetune my search a bit, and I found this:

[image: Honey Garlic Chicken Pizza]

There are higher res images of this available on Google, if you want to look into it. This Pizza is a Brunei specialty, "**Honey Garlic Chicken Pizza**." Looking at the various sample images, I feel fairly confident that this is the pizza in question. The biggest difference is how much *less green* the flecks of green are in your image, but it wouldn't surprise me that a real Pizza Hut would use slightly less ideal-looking ingredients than their marketing images would suggest.

While it does not seem to come with ranch by default, Pizza Hut allows for customization of orders, so probably this pizza had Ranch added to it, whether by the restaurant or by the customer afterwards.

If you'd like more pictures of the pizza in question, minus ranch, you can search for **"pizza hut brunei honey garlic chicken"**.

Let me know if anything doesn't quite check out.

**Edit: Pulling this into the answer from comments below, for posterity.**
I found this near the end of my investigating as well: pizzahut.com.bn/upload/images/pizza/ButterChickenMasala.jpg the image is labeled 'Butter chicken Masala' and has the trademark swirl, which I originally thought was ranch, but actually might be milk or cream.

Essentially, I have very little confidence in my original answer at this point. I would give 70-30 odds that your pizza is actually a Butter Chicken Masala pizza rather than the Honey Garlic that I initially thought, and odds are good that the white topping isn't even ranch like I originally assumed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can see the issue, for myself as I can safely say that I've never knowingly had 'Ranch dressing', it's not such a common condiment where I live in the UK, although that's not to say it doesn't occur under a different name ... It certainly does look like some kind of sweet glaze, in the image I provided anyway! Thank you for your answer so far, I appreciate you taking the time to do so! I must say, Honey and Garlic chicken sounds like quite an interesting combination. At a glance, I did wonder at first if it was lean pork, but then I realised that Brunei is Islamic!

Comment: @Cryogen I found this near the end of my investigating as well, for what it's worth: https://www.pizzahut.com.bn/upload/images/pizza/ButterChickenMasala.jpg the image is labeled 'Butter chicken Masala' and has the trademark Ranch dressing swirl, but I personally think that the Honey Garlic is a closer match other than that. This image does seem to suggest that the ranch is in use at this restaurant, either way. Good luck in your quest! Make sure to update the question if they respond on Twitter. :)

Comment: Unlikely to be a dessert with a bottle of Tabasco next to it :-)

Comment: @Cryogen I can confirm Ranch is not a popular dressing in the UK, it's a very US-based dressing. It's buttermilk-based with herbs in it. Rich, creamy, and fatty.

Comment: "it wouldn't surprise me that a real Pizza Hut would use slightly less ideal-looking ingredients than their marketing images would suggest" > Actually often food marketing pictures are not even real food. There are plenty very visual explanations on youtube...

Comment: @LaurentS.Yes, Indeed - it's rather a bit scary how we get lied to! Sadly, no reply from PHB to my tweet yet ...

Comment: The green flakes (oregano maybe?) - I'm guessing in the advertising photo they are sprinkled on the pizza after it's cooked, but in the OP's photo, they were put on before, so got a little burnt.  Or they used dried oregano(?) instead of fresh.

Comment: @Onyz Gosh, I could go either way from those photos, Masala or Honey Garlic, especially given the reddish chicken and orange-red splashes in OP's photo. More importantly, I would guess that a Masala pizza would not have Ranch dressing, but some raita-like sauce based on yogurt, or at least an imitation of such a sauce. Or possibly just a drizzle of cream or cream sauce, which isn't uncommon on butter chicken.

Comment: @Cryogen: I’d likewise never met ranch dressing until I moved to the US as an adult.  But you may well have tasted a flavour based on it: the Doritos we know as “Cool Original” in the UK are originally known, in the US, as “Cool Ranch”.

Comment: @Bloodgain The more I look into it, the more I'm inclined to agree. https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/118013119_3850776881604843_6795963776346944785_o.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=2&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_ohc=bYfFQht2G80AX-umMSc&_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.xx&oh=f9848e26ea75d4bb614822c9f20715ed&oe=5FE1E8E5 for example looks quite similar, but also dissimilar in many ways. I'm eager to see if the Brunei twitter responds.

Comment: Is ranch dressing even a thing in Brunei? It seems that making the assumption that an unnamed white sauce is ranch dressing is kind of myopic. It could be garlic sauce (https://brunei.desertcart.com/products/32375304-heinz-garlic-sauce-225-g) or a proprietary honey-garlic sauce, which is more likely... espcially knowing that Pizza Hut sells a Honey Garlic Chicken pizza in Brunei.

Comment: @GregNickoloff I have already edited my answer to reflect the possible inaccuracy of my original assumption.

Comment: @Onyz I see! Our posts must have crossed or something. I'm kind of wanting to try this pizza. The more we discuss it, the better it seems.